# How to set nvm and ESLint with VSCode globally?

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code, nvm

I want vscode eslint extensions works with nvm.

I got "Install ESLint global with `npm install -g eslint`" in vscode eslint estension console.

So, I've installed the eslint with nvm in terminal with `npm install -g eslint`, and set it, which in the path:

```
/Users/myname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules
```

Try to review the [official docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint), and find one solution to set `eslint.nodePath` in settings.json.

settings.json of vscode:

```
  "eslint.nodePath": "/Users/myname/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/lib/node_modules",
```

After set this property, the extension works well.

But, it would broke when I change node versions use nvm. I need to re-set `settings.json`.

Is there any solutions to set eslint in vscode with nvm?

I don't want to set settings.json when I change node versions with nvm each time.

I want to do it simple.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out after few hours hard work.

1. do NOT use fish as mac's default shell
2. set vscode user settings to:

```
  "terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/usr/local/bin/fish",
```

that you can use fish in vscode terminal

install `fisher`,
use

```
fisher add FabioAntunes/fish-nvm
fisher add edc/bass
```

that you can use nvm with fish

3. set your `.bash_profile` of nvm and nvm variables:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

add

```
fish
```

at the bottom

4. If you want to switch bash and fisher use:

```
# fish -> bash
bash --login 

# bash -> fish
fish
```

5. Enjoy `fish` and `nvm` and `eslint vscode plugin`

This will output of vscode console.

```
[Info  - 12:04:44 PM] ESLint server stopped.
[Info  - 12:04:45 PM] ESLint server running in node v10.11.0
[Info  - 12:04:45 PM] ESLint server is running.
```